# Add xib subview to specific position (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have used .xib to create some tableview cell. Each cell's height is 40

I want to use this custom cell to cover fully on the cell in my table view controller.

I tried to use cell.addSubview(cellLabel) and it helped to add subview on the top of the cell.

My question is how to add other xib subview under the first one so that i can cover fully of the cell.

Comment: Why are you adding it as subView when you return it self as cell ??

Comment: i want to create an expanding cell, that's mean if i click on the cell, it will expand and provide other options. each option can be clicked to perform action

Comment: What you are looking for is a expand/collapse tableview.
Check this one out https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView   Hope it helps